# How to print list of instances of \cite in bibliography entry

Tags: biblatex, custom-bib

I want each of my bibliography entries to contain a list of every location where the item is cited (i.e. using `\cite`) in the work. Similar to the output of `\pageref`.

example.bib

```
@book{key,
    title = {Not a Real Title},
    author = {John Doe},
    date = {2020}
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\cite{key}
\lipsum[4-6]
\cite{key}\cite{key}
\end{document}
```

The output should look something like this:

Doe, John. Not a Real Title. 2020. Cited on Pages 1, 2(2)

Where the number in parentheses refers to the number of times it was cited on that page. Is this possible?

Comment: biblatex has an option for it. Adding `backref=true` to your biblatex's options should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`biblatex` has an option for it. Adding `backref=true` to your biblatex's options should be enough.

It, on top of it, you would like these references to be hyperlinked, you can load `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{example.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\cite{key}
\lipsum[4-6]
\cite{key}\cite{key}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]